# Angular custom selector in primeng <p-table> body template not working properly

Tags: angular, primeng

I have angular html component:

```
 <p-table
                [value]="baseDataAgg.baseData"
                [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
                styleClass="p-datatable-sm"
                selectionMode="single">

               <!-- Headers -->

                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-ri="rowIndex" >

                    <td>.................</td>
                    <jhi-test></jhi-test>

                </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

`<jhi-test>` selector component is genereting html columns based on some input data and some logic.
When I display table columns that are genereted by `<jhi-test>` are not streched for full
row and they are not styled by  component.
For me it looks like  is not bind/connected to `pTemplate="body"`.
Is there any way to make it work?